# Finding min, max, inf, sup for $\frac{m*n}{4m^2+n^2}; m\in \mathbb{Z}, n \in \mathbb{N}$

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

What is the proper way to find $\inf, \sup, \max, \min$ for:

$A=\{\frac{m*n}{4m^2+n^2}; m\in \mathbb{Z}, n \in \mathbb{N}\}$

I'm not sure what is the proper proof outline for this case. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Check for $m = 0$ and $n = 0$. Then ($n \neq 0 \wedge m \neq 0$) divide numerator and denominator by $mn \neq 0$.
$$
A = \left\lbrace \frac{1}{4 \frac{m}{n} + \frac{n}{m}} \left| m \in \mathbb{Z}\smallsetminus \lbrace 0 \rbrace \wedge n \in \mathbb{N}\smallsetminus \lbrace 0 \rbrace\right.\right\rbrace \cup \lbrace 0 \rbrace
$$

Now let $q = \frac{m}{n}$. $q \in \mathbb{Q} \smallsetminus \lbrace 0 \rbrace$. So:
$$
A = \left\lbrace \frac{1}{4q + \frac{1}{q}}; q \in \mathbb{Q} \smallsetminus \lbrace 0 \rbrace \right\rbrace \cup \ \lbrace 0 \rbrace
$$

I have good day, so I made your homework. But think next time, please.

Comment: +- for your last sentence.

Comment: Not homework, unfortunately : ) Some of us are here to learn, some of us are here to downvote and judge

Comment: @OssLog So, welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level.See:
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559), 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773) and 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/)